# The existence of x around x0 in the definition of convergence of a function in Analysis Tao

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is the definitions in Analysis I of Tao,

> Definition 9.3.1 (ε-closeness). Let X be a subset of R, let f : X → R
>   be a function, let L be a real number, and let ε > 0 be a real number.
>   We say that the function f is ε-close to L iff f(x) is ε-close to L
>   for every x ∈ X.
>
> Definition 9.3.3 (Local ε-closeness). Let X be a subset of R, let f :
>   X → R be a function, let L be a real number, x0 be an adherent point
>   of X, and ε > 0 be a real number. We say that f is ε-close to L near
>   x0 iff there exists a δ > 0 such that f becomes ε-close to L when
>   restricted to the set {x ∈ X : |x − x0| < δ}.
>
> Definition 9.3.6 (Convergence of functions at a point). Let X be a
>   subset of R, let f : X → R be a function, let E be a subset of X, x0
>   be an adherent point of E, and let L be a real number. We say that f
>   converges to L at x0 in E, and write limx→x0;x∈E f(x) = L, iff f,
>   after restricting to E, is ε-close to L near x0 for every ε > 0. If f
>   does not converge to any number L at x0, we say that f diverges at x0,
>   and leave limx→x0;x∈E f(x) undefined.

My question is since the definition 9.3.6 only requires the existence of δ for any ε as such, is it true that it is **not** necessary that there must be some x, other than x0 itself, that is δ-close to x0 to ensure limit of f(x) exist?

---

**Update**: I tried to make a counterexample but failed to show such x is necessary. For example, function f from {1,2,3} to N st, f(0) = 1, f(1) = 2, and f(2) = 3. Using the definition, though there is no x that is 1/2-close to 1 other than 1, |f(1) - f(1)| is ε-close for any ε.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=\{0\}$ then any function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ has  a limit at $0$ and it is continuous at $0$ according to this definition. It is not necessary that there are other points in the domain close to $0$.